# Changing/removing DirectX versions

Tags: windows-7, directx

I have been having some issues and i wanted some help regarding the DirectX issues on my Windows 7. My graphics card supports DirectX 9 and i have DirectX 11 installed due to reinstalling Windows. I wish to downgrade to DirectX 9, removing all traces of DirectX 11. Is there any way to do this? Any help would really be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @M4t1-1 - Have you actually installed the DirectX 9.0c Runtime?

Comment: @Sanu_012 - [Windows 7 has DirectX 11 not DirectX 10.  While Windows 7 SP1 has DirectX 11.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/179113/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-directx).  Virtual XP would not be able to run the applications the author wants to run, the performance within a VM, would be absolutely horrible.  *DirectX 9.0c can be installed on Windows 7*

Comment: @M4t1-1 - No; There are no updates to DirectX 11.1 on Windows 7.  There are no stand-alone DirectX installers other than DirectX 9.0c for **any** version of Windows.  Since you don't indicate what errors you have received, or really any information about your problem, I am unable to address your actual problem.  Since your question is straight forward, I did submit an answer, what you want is simply not possible.

Comment: @M4t1-1 - I don't actually know what your issue is exactly.  You have provided zero information, other then a generic statement, you receive errors.  If a DirectX application actually runs, but there is a blank window, then the problem isn't with DirectX.  The problem more than likely is a hardware compatibility issue, in other words, your hardware does not meet the minimum requirements for the application.

Comment: @M4t1-1 - What you describe is not a DirectX issue.  I am not going to reply to any additional comments.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, the performance will surely be horrible, but the amount of details OP has furnished, I could help only that much :|

Comment: Hmm sorry for the inconvenience then, thanks for the help. Ill see on my end what to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to downgrade to DirectX 9, removing all traces of DirectX 11.

**What you want to do is not possible.**  However, you can install the current DirectX 9.0c release and install that.  It absolutely is not possible to remove DirectX 11.1 from Windows 7 Service Pack 1

[Microsoft DirectX® 9.0c End-User Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34429)

I should point out, there are multiple DirectX 9.0 Runtime releases, so you must install the specific DirectX 9.0c Runetime that the application was compiled against.  If you are able to start the application, then you already have it installed, installing version I linked will not solve your problems.

**DirectX 11.1 is able to run applications in Direct X 9 mode, however, they must be explicitly compiled to use that DirectX 11.1 mode.**

> Is there any way to do this?

If you wanted to downgrade to Direct X 9, you would have to downgrade to Windows XP, but that presents it's own issues.